# How can I prevent my bottom toolbar with 3 images from being stretched out?

Tags: android, image, layout, toolbar, android-layout-weight

I have a bottom layout with three images. I want them to be equally distributed. To do this, I used the `layout_weight` xml property. But the visual representation of them is awful – the images are all stretched out

[image: bottom layout]

The images' dimension is 32*32.

The layout code for this particular toolbar is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar     
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/toolbar_bottom"
xmlns:appo="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:minHeight="50dp"
android:background="#ffff8c0e"
appo:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"
android:minWidth="50dp"
android:elevation="10dp"
>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/toolbarmenucontainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/camera_image"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="true"

        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/camera_icon"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/news_image"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:clickable="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_weight = "1"
        android:src="@drawable/new_icon"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/facebook_image"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"

        android:clickable="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/facebooc_image"
       />
</LinearLayout>
```

How can I make them appear properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

wrap `ImageView` in another layout say `RelativeLayout`.

i.e do something like this.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:appo="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_bottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffff8c0e"
    android:elevation="10dp"
    android:minHeight="50dp"
    android:minWidth="50dp"
    appo:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme" >

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/toolbarmenucontainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/camera_image"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/camera_icon" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/news_image"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/new_icon" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/facebook_image"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/facebooc_image" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 3):

> Remove `android:scaleType="fitXY"` from your code.Because All it does is scale the bitmap up to the size of the ImageView.

**Refer this.**

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbarmenucontainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/camera_image"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/news_image"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/facebook_image"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I had to wrap each image inside a relative layout. But thanks for the answer.:)

Comment: @Theo If you will use my trick it result the same. Why you are adding extra code in your XML.No need to add more `Relative Layout` in your code. it will ran perfect by remove only `android:scaleType`.

Answer (score 0):

Just use RelativeLayout like this:

```
<RelativeLayout  android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/camera_image"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/camera_icon"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/news_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/new_icon"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/facebook_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/facebooc_image"/></RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

set your imageview scale type as you want, there are different options

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

or
`center`, `centerCrop`,`centerInside`,`fitCenter` etc

Answer (score 0):

There is this nice [library](https://github.com/sephiroth74/Material-BottomNavigation) that solves by problem:). It uses bottom navigation.