# Alinging menu items of a toolbar in the center

Tags: android, menu, toolbar

Is it possible to align the menu icons of a toolbar in the center? I used another way shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37248679/bottom-toolbar-with-3-images/37248775?noredirect=1#comment62026031_37248775),but there I was putting images inside my Toolbar layout. Now I want to try it with menu icons:).

[image: my layout]

here is my code.

**bottm toolbar**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar   
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:appo="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:minHeight="50dp"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
appo:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"
appo:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
```

**menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/news"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:icon="@drawable/new_icon"
    android:title="News">

</item>

<item
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:id="@+id/camera"
    android:icon="@drawable/camera_icon"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="Camera"
   ></item>
<item
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:id="@+id/facebook"
    android:icon="@drawable/facebooc_image"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="Camera"
    >
</item>
```

Comment: there is not such way to center  the optionsMenu , you have to put that inside `Toolbar`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ToolBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html) is just a [ViewGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html). You can add Images into to it just like into a RelativeLayout or LinearLayout. for example,

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@color/white_color"
        android:textSize="@dimen/textSize12" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of trying to center menuItem , you can try the below handy implementation :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

        // Here is the main code for  your Midle Buttons
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center">
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:id="@+id/button1"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:id="@+id/button2"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:id="@+id/button3"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:id="@+id/button4" />
        </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:
`app:buttonGravity="center_vertical"` inside toolbar