# How can I distribute toolbar items across the screen horizontally?

Tags: android, kotlin, toolbar

Apologies for the beginner question, continuing an app project I build during my first semester in Kotlin.

The items are locked to the right of the screen even after setting the app title to nothing. I want the items evenly distributed across the toolbar horizontally with no title present.

main_menu:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

      <item android:id="@+id/action_view_hunts"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_sharp_catching_pokemon_24"
        android:title="@string/hunts"
        app:showAsAction= "always" />
      <item android:id="@+id/action_add_hunt"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_fiber_new_24"
        android:title="@string/new_hunt"
        app:showAsAction="always|withText"/>
      <item android:id="@+id/action_view_history"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_history_24"
        android:title="@string/history"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
      <item android:id="@+id/action_view_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_settings_applications_24"
        android:title="Settings"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>

    </menu>
```

The toolbar is thrown into each activity, here's one example:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HuntsActivity">

    <!--  Toolbar  -->
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/bootRed"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
    <!--  end Toolbar  -->
```

The bar is setup in the activity with the usual binding:

```kotlin
    setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar)
    supportActionBar?.title = ""
    
    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu)

        val huntsMenuItem = menu?.findItem(R.id.action_view_hunts)
        huntsMenuItem?.setIcon(R.drawable.baseline_catching_pokemon_24_black)

        return true
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to move the menu items into center.

Please look for this, if this can give you an idea: [Alinging menu items of a toolbar in the center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37249590/alinging-menu-items-of-a-toolbar-in-the-center)

But, if you want a tabs, please consider doing a TabLayout for this one. For your reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/tabs/TabLayout

I think, your goal is to have tabs. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. I decided to rework it into a BottomNavigationView instead as that implemented my desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

I simply decided to rework things into a BottomNavigationView instead of using a toolbar. This created the functionality I desired.

```
<!--  Navigation  -->
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottomNav"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:menu="@menu/main_menu"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
<!--  end Navigation  -->
```

Reworking the xml to this, and the rest to this:

```
binding.bottomNav.selectedItemId = R.id.action_view_hunts

binding.bottomNav.setOnItemSelectedListener {
    when (it.itemId) {
        R.id.action_add_hunt -> { startActivity(Intent(applicationContext, NewHuntActivity::class.java)) }
        R.id.action_view_history -> { startActivity(Intent(applicationContext, CompletedHuntsActivity::class.java)) }
        R.id.action_view_settings -> { startActivity(Intent(applicationContext, SettingsActivity::class.java)) }

        else -> {}
        }
        true
    }
```

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score -1):

This is only for your reference customize it according your need, let me know if it solve your problem.........

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Testing.TestActivity">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/ic_1"
                android:layout_height="50dp"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/ic_2"
                android:layout_height="50dp"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/ic_3"
                android:layout_height="50dp"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:id="@+id/ic_4"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:id="@+id/ic_5"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```